# Why are f-strings not printed in Python class methods?

Tags: python, f-string

I would like to understand why f-strings do not print output in class methods. I would like to use their concise syntax for making breakpoints.

MWE:

```
class FStringTest:
    def test(self):
        print('why does this work')
        f'but not this'

print(FStringTest().test())
f'yet this works'
```

Output:

```
why does this work
None
yet this works
```

Comment: You need to return the string you want to use outside the class method, i.e. `return f'but not this'`

Comment: The REPL is the one printing the value of your expression. If you ran that as a script, neither one would print anything.

Comment: Have you tried regular strings in the same situations?   You will find that you get the output only if it's the very last statement of your program.  to prove this, type `True` as the last line of your program after the string.

Comment: `f'yet this works'` Does not print anything. It only gets shown because you've entered it to the interactive interpreter (=Python shell / REPL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this in Jupyter or an interactive python shell?
Because if you were, then the 'P' in REPL, which stands for print (R=READ,E=EVALUATE,P=PRINT,L=LOOP), will print the `yet this works` automatically for you without you explicitly calling the print function.

So:

```
why does this work
```

This is what the print inside your method returns.

```
None
```

You're seeing this because you're printing the value that your test() method is returning, and since it happens that it returns nothing (no return) it gives you this 'None' value.

```
yet this works
```

This is just what the REPL echoing back to you.

Note: Save this as a python script (.py) and try running it in an IDE like VSC, or via the command line using `py <script_name>.py`, it will not show you that last line of output.